# How to connect Sparkfun M6E Nano UHF Rfid reader and ESP8266 NodeMCU 0.1

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu, rfid

I am using an ESP8266 NodeMCU v0.1 and Sparkfun M6E Nano UHF Rfid reader. How to connect NodeMCU to M6E Nano UHF Rfid reader?

Comment: did you see my answer?

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes i saw your answer.

Comment: @Juraj can you tell me that is there any way to post an array (20 byte) using nodemcu on MySQL data base which is on my localhost. because i am getting my RFID tag id into an array! Like this

FF, DE, 3E, X, X, X....... till 20 bytes

Comment: it is possible, but that is a different question. you would need to have a server on a computer to write the data to MySQL. and you would send data from esp8266 to this server.

Comment: Thanks, yes i already have a server(xampp) on a computer. Could you provide the resource/link that how to insert array into a single cell of database?

Comment: Yes i had insert  the temperature sensor data into a MySQL database using nodemcu, but don't know how it could be done for an array!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface of Sparkfun M6E Nano UHF Rfid reader is Serial TTL. So you should connect it to Serial pins of the NodeMcu. Don't use USB then, because it is connect to Serial too.

Comment: worked fine with Arduino Uno when I am trying to use with Uno+Rfid reader+NodeMcu it doesn't work!

Comment: how did you wire it to nodemcu?

Comment: Like this
(Reader->NodeMCU),
GND ->GND,
VIN->VIN,
RST->RST,
2->D2,
3->D3,

Comment: this answer above says you should connect it to RX and TX

Comment: use the pins on the short side of the reader board, VCC, Gnd, RX and TX and connect to Gnd, 5V, Rx and TX of NodeMcu

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/simultaneous-rfid-tag-reader-hookup-guide/all#hardware-hookup

Comment: You are saying about TX/RX pins which are used for Arduino Shield, not for FDTI.

Comment: it is not only for FTDI. it is Serial. and you need Serial. With Uno, you used pins 2 and 3 with SoftwareSerial. you can't do that with NodeMcu. you could connect the NodeMcu to pins 0 and 1, but why. those are the same RX and TX pins as 'for the FTDI'